# I am getting error while using package CarouselSlider it display error type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'String' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel

It shows url images from network but doesnot shows images from assests asI am trying to access image from assests .

list of images from assests inside my flutter project:

```
int _current = 0;
  final List imgList = [
    Image.asset('assests/GL.png'),
    Image.asset('assests/GL.png'),
    Image.asset('assests/GL.png'),
     ];
```

code in CarouselSlider

```
CarouselSlider(
                  height: 200,
                  initialPage: 0,
                  enlargeCenterPage: true,
                  autoPlay: true,
                  reverse: false,
                  enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                  autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
                  autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                  pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 10),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  onPageChanged: (index){
                    setState(() {
                      _current = index;
                    });
                  },


                  items: imgList.map((imgUrl){

                    return Builder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context){
                      return Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
                        child: Image.assest(imgUrl,fit:BoxFit.fill),//error line in code
                      );
                      },
                    );

                }).toList(),),
            SizedBox(height: 20,),
              ],
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: Please add your pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the urls in your list instead of Image Widgets. Change your List to:

```
final List imgList = [
    'assests/GL.png',
    'assests/GL.png',
    'assests/GL.png',
];
```